# How to extract distinct part of a string from a file in linux

Tags: linux

I'm using the following command to extract distinct urls that contain .com extension and may contain .us or whatever country extension.

```
 grep '\.com' source.txt -m 700 | uniq | sed -e 's/www.//' 
> dest.txt
```

The problem is that, it extracts urls in the same doamin, the thing tht I don't want. Ex:
abc.yahoo.com
efg.yahoo.com

I only need the yahoo.com. How can I using grep or any other command extract distinct domain names only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
egrep -io '[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}(\.[a-z]{2})?' source.txt
```

Comment: It is not necessarily us, the file may contain different extensions like us, uk , etc.

Comment: Yes. This served: egrep -io '[a-z0-9\-]+\.com(\.[a-z]{2})?' source.txt -m 100 | uniq | sed -e 's/www.//' > dest.txt except one thing. Why uniq does not do what it is supposed to do ?? i.e, if I have abc.yahoo.com & efg.yahoo.com, the new dest file contains two entries for yahoo.com ??

Comment: @JuryA uniq only removes adjacent duplicates, try piping the output to `sort` first: `egrep -io '[a-z0-9\-]+\.com(\.[a-z]{2})?' source.txt -m 100 | sort | uniq | sed -e 's/www.//' > dest.txt `

Comment: What do you mean by adjacent?? Two consecutive line ??

Comment: @JuryA Yeah, if these were lines: `A, B, A` the A's won't get removed, but `A, A, B` will have the extra A's removed: `A, B`

Comment: I have a huge file. when I write the command as: `[a-z0-9\-]+\.com(\.[a-z]{2})?' source.txt | sort | uniq | sed -e 's/www.//' > dest.txt` without specifying max number, it does not work. I open the destination file & it is empty, and the last modified date does not change which means no writing happens. When i specify small number in the parameter -m I get the correct output. What is wrong ?

Comment: @JuryA You may want to think about using [split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) to split the very large file into somewhat more manageable chunks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using awk in instead of sed and specify "." as the delimiter and only print out the two last fields.

```
awk -F "." '{ print $(NF-1)"."$NF }'
```

Comment: It might be .com.us or .com.sa etc. Will this serve ?

Comment: I tried, it didn't help. For example, if you have: abc.yahoo.com, it prints abc.yahoo

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this should help:

```
egrep -o '[^.]*.com' file
```

Comment: I think this should work except for one part, would it give me the second domain extension like .com.us or .com.uk ?? I need that.

Comment: I tried it. It works perfectly but does not serve in the multiple extensions such as: .com.us , .com.sa. Any idea how to make it work for both cases ?