# egrep not writing to a file

Tags: linux

I am using the following command in order to extract domain names & the full domain extension from a file. Ex: www.abc.yahoo.com, www.efg.yahoo.com.us.

```
[a-z0-9\-]+\.com(\.[a-z]{2})?' source.txt | sort | uniq | sed -e 's/www.//' 
> dest.txt
```

The command write correctly when I specify small maximum parameter `-m 100` after the `source.txt`. The problem if I didn't specify, or if I specified a huge number. Although, I could write to files with grep (not egrep) before with huge numbers similar to what I'm trying now and that was successful. I also check the last modified date and time during the command being executed, and it seems there is no modification happening in the destination file. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Most versions of `sort` on linux have `-u` as a parameter to do the `uniq` step.  Try it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712081/how-to-extract-distinct-part-of-a-string-from-a-file-in-linux), it's probably not an issue with `egrep`, but that your file is too big and that `sort` won't output anything (to `uniq`) until egrep is done. I suggested that you split the files into manageable chucks using the [split](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) command. Something like this:

```
split -l 10000000 source.txt split_source.
```

This will split the `source.txt` file into 10 million line chunks called `split_source.a`, `split_source.b`, `split_source.c` etc. And you can run the entire command on each one of those files (and maybe changing the pipe to append at the end: `>> dest.txt`).

The problem here is that you can get duplicates across multiple files, so at the end you may need to run

```
sort dest.txt | uniq > dest_uniq.txt
```

Comment: The file was just too big. I waited for longer time and it wrote on it. I had doubt because of the last modified date and time was showing me no progress or modification is happening.

Comment: @JuryA Yeah, it's because `sort` won't output anything until it gets all of the data from `egrep` (in order to properly sort), so nothing happens to the file at all until egrep is completely done.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing information.

That aside, a few thoughts.  First, to debug and isolate your problem:

1. Run the `egrep <params> | less` so you can see what `egreps` doing, and eliminate any problem from `sort`, `uniq`, or `sed` (my bets on `sort`).
2. How big is your input?  Any chance `sort` is dying from too much input?
3. Gonna need to see the full command to make further comments.

Second, to improve your script:

1. You may want to `sort | uniq` AFTER `sed`, otherwise you could end up with duplicates in your result set, AND an unsorted result set.  Maybe that's what you want.
2. Consider wrapping your regular expressions with "^...$", if it's appropriate to establish beginning of line (^) and end of line ($) anchors.  Otherwise you'll be matching portions in the middle of a line.